# how to display posts by month asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Basically my post table:

```
public partial class Mak
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
    public DateTime writingDate{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to list posts grouped months with for each on my view.
**My Code:**

```
@foreach (var tar in Model.Mak.OrderByDescending(x=> x.writingDate.Month).Select(x=> x.writingDate))
{
    <a href="/m/Date?year=@tar.Year&month=@tar.Month">@tar.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</a>

    @foreach (var mak in Model.Mak.Where(x=> x.writingDate==tar))
    {
        <a href="/m/@mak.Name"></a><div> @mak.Name</div>
    }

 }
```

**Output:**

```
   July 2017
Connected //post name

   July  2017
Linq to SQL

   July 2017
OOP

   July 2017
Linq Querys
```

**Desired Output:**

```
   June 2017
xyz //post name
abc    
   July 2017
Connected 
Linq to SQL
OOP
Linq Querys
```

How should I write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@{
    // gets the records grouped based on Year and Month. 
    // Creates an object of IEnumerable<IGrouping<>> type
    var groupedByMonth = Model.Mak
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.writingDate)
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.writingDate.Year, x.writingDate.Month });

    // loop thorugh each group 
    foreach (var group in groupedByMonth)
    {
        // each group will have 2 "Keys" with Month and Year value.
        // or use Url.Action() to form your anchor 
        <a href="/m/Date?year=@group.Key.Year&month=@group.Key.Month">@group.FirstOrDefault().writingDate.ToString("MMMM yyyy")</a> <br>

        // looping through contents of group
        // IGrouping inherits from IEnumerable, so this is possible
        foreach (var mak in group)
        {
            <a href="/m/@mak.Name"><div> @mak.Name</div> </a><br>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by your collection using month and year and then loop through the grouped items.

```
@{
    var posts = Model.Mak; // Assuming this is the list of posts;
    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
    var postGrouped = posts.GroupBy(x => new { Month = x.WritingDate.Month,
                                                         Year = x.WritingDate.Year });
}
@foreach (var item in postGrouped)
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("date","m",new { year=item.Key.Year, month=item.Key.Month})">
                        @dtfi.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(item.Key.Month) @item.Key.Year</a>
    foreach (var post in item)
    {
        <div>
            <a href="/m/@(post.Title)">@post.Title</a>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The `GetAbbreviatedMonthName` method takes the integer representing the month and return the string name.

I would also recommend using the html helper methods to render the href value (Use `Url.Action` or `Html.ActionLink` helper methods) of the link. Also consider following the PascalCasing approach when writing C# classes. (`WritingDate` instead of `writingDate`)

Comment: thanks for advices bro, let me ask one question to u, why should i following the PascalCasing approach?

Comment: You do not need to. But that is what the industry does. See what Microsoft does https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions.md